# how can i unhide a specific worksheet in multiple excel files. the worksheet were hidden using vba?

Tags: excel, vba, file, editing

I'm updating a sheet that contains reference that in multiple excel files. this specific sheet is hidden using vba ( xlSheetVeryHidden). I'm trying to unhide them so I can update the contents of the sheet.

Comment: You will need to open the VBE,(Alt-F11) then select the sheet and in the properties of that sheet you can change it.

Comment: Please be sure to [do research](https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+unhide+xlveryhidden) before asking here, this is a relatively straightforward question/answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Unhide()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        'Check worksheet name
        If ws.Name = "Test" Then
            ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: This might work for one file but I have more that 300 files that I wanted to unhide the  workshhet ..

Comment: Yes i know, a give you the 90% of the solution in your problem. Stackoverflow is not a free coding website. Do a research, show some effort post your piece of code and we will help you.